# iOS UIImage clip to paths

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm working with an image where the user has selected part of it using UIBezierPath. How can I delete/clear out/make transparent everything that is not part of that selection?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With one path it's very easy.  Just set the path as the clipping path:

```
- (UIImage *)maskImage:(UIImage *)originalImage toPath:(UIBezierPath *)path {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, 0);
    [path addClip];
    [originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return maskedImage;
}
```

If you want to use the union of multiple paths, it's harder, because Quartz doesn't have any functions that directly compute the union of two paths.  One way is to fill each path one by one into a mask, and then draw the image through the mask:

```
- (UIImage *)maskedImage
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
    rect.size = self.originalImage.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0.0); {
        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(rect);
        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        for (UIBezierPath *path in self.paths)
            [path fill];
    }
    UIImage *mask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0); {
        CGContextClipToMask(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, mask.CGImage);
        [self.originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }
    UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return maskedImage;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Had no idea it was so easy. I was looking in all the wrong places. Clipping restricts the drawing area, right?

Comment: Huh, I have multiple nsbezierpaths, or if I have one nsbezierpath where strokes are on top of each other this gets screwed.

Comment: Sorry, this actually doesn't work. I have multiple UIBezierPath which don't necessarily represent shapes that clip wants, but selections. Clipping on multiple UIBezierPaths that sometimes are one over the other doesn't return the proper image.

Comment: @robmayoff Following your first example work well except that my image keep its original file size. I cannot adjust the image to its content using the ContentMode or changing its frame. Do you know hoy can I do it? [CurrentResult](https://postimg.org/image/qcaoqc4dj/)

Comment: This Swift answer shows how to clip using a UIBezierPath and get an image with an alpha channel in PNG format.  It also show how to save the clip to the camera roll and how to place it into the pasteboard.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853122/swift-clipping-image-with-uibezierpath/65533953#65533953

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code of union multiple paths, and it doesn't work.

Actually, if the union of paths don't overlap with each other, we append one path to another and crop with the final path.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImg.size, NO, 0);
[path1 appendPath:path2]; // append path2 to path1
[path1 addClip];

[originalImg drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```