# Crop center of the UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, crop

At present, I am working on core graphics based iPhone application. 
I have tried to crop center of the image but i can't do that.
Here,I have an images named **(fig a)** as shown below, and i need to crop it on center of this image. 
So, the resultant image should look like **(fig b)**.

How can i do this?.

fig a :

[image]

fig b :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer :**

1. I think what you want is : [iOS UIImage clip to paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8308955/1603072). Rob has described how to remove selected part of `UIImage` using `UIBezierPath`. You can customize it for yourself to get what you want.
2. You can also use some View as a Mask above that Central Part.

Comment: Thanks Vin.. I have tried this but no luck.. i could not get the resultant image fig b. Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [BJIMageCropper](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper)

Hope This will helps you